# Meilisearch Cloud with local Postgres

Tags: meilisearch

The code is working fine as I tried it on the local server meilisearch. The products are getting indexed and the value is being shown.

But using the same process and code  I am unable to get indexes on the Meilisearch Cloud.

I have followed the below documentation:-

1. Medusa-Meilisearch offical documentation - https://docs.medusajs.com/plugins/search/meilisearch
2. Meilisearch local setup offical documentation - https://www.meilisearch.com/docs/learn/getting_started/quick_start
3. Meilisearch Cloud setup offical documentation -https://www.meilisearch.com/docs/learn/getting_started/cloud_quick_start
4. Meiliesearch Postgresql sync documentation -https://www.meilisearch.com/docs/learn/cookbooks/meilisync_postgresql